# DirectX access from Windows service

Tags: windows, winapi, directx

Can DirectX API be used from Windows Service running at Session 0? I know services can't display GUI. I would like to call APIs that not involved in GUI display. Will the API calls fail? Windows 8 and above are of interest.

Comment: This blog says Yes for Direct2D: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/04/16/using-direct2d-from-a-service-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure on what you would like to use but it is possible to use the DirectX datatypes in a Windows Service. GUI calls as you have stated will not be displayed. Depending on what call you make(Example):

- Drawing to the screen will fail
- Saving objects of DirectX datatypes/using DirectX datatypes inside your service to interact with other variables you might will work.